# gRPC Retry using someApi.withOption

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java, retry-logic

Is it possible to use .withOption to add retryPolicy configurations to a grpc client stub? I've tried something like below but it seems it fails to equals on the key. Is there a better way of doing this please?

```
val someApi: OfferTokenAPIGrpcKt.OfferTokenAPICoroutineStub

someApi.withOption(CallOptions.Key.create("io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelServiceConfig.MethodInfo"), createMethodInfo())
.randomGrpcEndpoint()

    fun createMethodInfo(): Map<String, Map<String, Any>> {
        val statusCodes = listOf("UNAVAILABLE", "UNKNOWN")
        val retryPolicyMap = mapOf(
            "maxAttempts" to "5",
            "initialBackoff" to "2s",
            "maxBackoff" to "30s",
            "backoffMultiplier" to "2",
            "retryableStatusCodes" to statusCodes,
        )

        val methodConfig = mapOf("retryPolicy" to retryPolicyMap)

        return methodConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot specify the retry policy per-RPC. `CallOptions.Key` use reference equality, so simply creating a key with the same name does nothing other than reuse the debug string.

You can specify a service config via [`ManagedChannelbuilder.defaultServiceConfig()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#defaultServiceConfig-java.util.Map-). That allows you to configure a method's retry policy, but that does not allow you to change the settings per-RPC.